# How to get a copy of private key xCode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ionic-framework, xcode8

[I am facing this issue in order to create a build. Please help if someone also faced this issue before.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMjFs.jpg)[This is the screenshot of the issue I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMjFs.jpg)

Comment: Delete existing certificate from KeyChain and re-download them an install it, close Xcode and reopen Xcode again.

Comment: Take `.p12` file from machine in which you have created certificate and install that  `.p12` to add in your keychain. I think have directly added certificate files in keychain. So you have public key but missing private key.

Comment: You should ask the creator of the certificate to send you the private key associated with that . In your case It is swati , so you can ash her to export the private keys for these certificates from the Keychain access app on Mac and send that to you so that you can import those private keys into your Keychain Access .

Comment: @BharatJagtap In my case I have that account credentials .but owner dont have knowledge about private keys. Can you please tell me how can export private keys from there system. Please..

Comment: @ANDROIDDEVELOPER If you have access to the mac machine then open Keychain Access select the private key under the correct certificate , right click and select export . There are plenty of tutorials available on the internet about keychain usage . If you are not able to access the Mac machine then simply delete the certificate from developer portal and re-create a new one. Next edit the provisioning profile and attach this newly created certificate there ,save and download this new provisioning profile . It should work fine.